# Problem while launching Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

whenever I "roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch" the terminal freezes after displaying the following message

"Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Insufficient GL support
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 3093, exit code -11].
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

"

I think my laptop is working on onboard intel graphic card which is causing this problem. Although I have nvidia graphic card already installed I am not sure it is active. I don't know what the problem is.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11224/problem-while-launching-gazebo/) by [Abhishek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1088/abhishek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-09-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently figured out that my laptop has optimus Setup. In an attempt to solve this I tried installing bumblebee, which was the only online solution to this. but that also did not work.
Is there any other way?

---

Originally posted by [Abhishek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1088/abhishek/) with karma: 26 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-29**:
Only a limited number of graphics cards are supported by the underlying rendering engine.  See http://answers.ros.org/question/210/gazebo-supported-graphics-card

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check glxinfo output. It should note something like:

```
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
```

Ubuntu can usually install the proprietary nVidia driver from the additional driver menu which should fix the problem. If your laptop has an Optimus Setup you might have a bigger problem.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-15**:
also check running headless http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/RunningSimulatorHeadless if applies